# Sort array based on another array, both position and string [ES6]

Tags: javascript, arrays

If I have an array of types...

```
const types = ['train','bus','car']; 
// needs to re-ordered to represent the order belonging to transportationFields.
```

And an array of fields...

```
const transportationFields = [
      'bus_station', 'bus_stop', 'bus_line', 'took_bus' // bus -> 1st in the order
      'car_type', 'buyer_of_car', 'car_model', // car -> 2nd 
      'train_number', 'train_trip_num', 'train_stop', // train -> 3rd 
    ];
```

I'd like to re-order the types array to match the order of the transportationFields array. The only way I can think of making this work would be to filter based on string and then sort...

Expected output: `const newTypes = ['bus','car','train'];`

I've tried this:

```
const newTypes = transportationFields.filter((pos) => types.indexOf(pos) > -1);
```

But that literally looks to the exact string name. How can I sort based on if the string of the types is present in the transportationFields order? Thank you for your help in advance. (Using React ES6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const transportationFields = [
  'bus_station', 'bus_stop', 'bus_line', 'took_bus', // bus -> 1st in the order
  'car_type', 'buyer_of_car', 'car_model', // car -> 2nd 
  'train_number', 'train_trip_num', 'train_stop', // train -> 3rd 
];

const types = ['train', 'bus', 'car'];

function findIndex(a) {
  return transportationFields.findIndex(function(v) { // returns index where condition is true
    return v.includes(a) // condition is true if the value includes the string given
  })
}

types.sort(function(a, b) {
  return findIndex(a) > findIndex(b)
})

console.log(types)
```

Comment: hmm still returns ['train', 'bus', 'car'] for me. I might have failed to convert to es6 correctly

Comment: const is just a way of initializing a variable. similar to "var a = 1;"

Comment: Mmm works fine for me on chrome, which browser are you on?

Comment: Chrome. I thought I made a mistake converting it... But I ran it through a js to es6 converter still it still doesn't work. :\

Comment: `function findIndex(a) {
  return transportationFields.findIndex(v => v.includes(a))
}

types.sort((a, b) => findIndex(a) > findIndex(b))`

Comment: Does it throw an error or the order doesn't change? Also, what does the run code snippet show?

Comment: doesn't change the order. i'm logging via console and yeah it's not changing. No errors are thrown.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111905/discussion-between-juvian-and-modelesq).